# Why are my database queries limited to 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my controller query:

```
@statuses = Status.find_by user_id: (params[:id])
```

and here's its output:

```
 Status Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "statuses".* FROM "statuses" WHERE "statuses"."user_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
```

Just curious as to where that `LIMIT 1` is coming from...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> find_by finds the first record matching some conditions

use where instead to find all

`Status.where(user_id: params[:id])`

As a note, if you follow the logic of `find_by`, you'll see it basically does:

`where(*args).limit(1).to_a.first`

Comment: You also have ```find_all_by``` methods. In any case, all those methods are deprecated and probably shouldn't be used.